# How Do I Access The Spring Boot Startup Actuator During A Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to record the startup information about my application during a Spring Boot test.  I have the startup actuator configured and working in Spring Boot 'bootrun' mode.  However, when I try to access that actuator during a test using a TestRestTemplate, I get a 404 error.

I have written an example program that demonstrates the problem.  The issue isn't with acutators overall as I have the metrics and health actuators working in the same test.  Just the startup actuator.

The example code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/danielshiplett/actuator-test)

Comment: You're not starting an entire application in your tests, you're only starting a single component.  You *shouldn't* require the actuator in your tests, and your test framework wouldn't allow the server to live long enough for you to be able to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this so I thought I would post it.  For complete details, see the original repo in GitHub and check the [solution branch](https://github.com/danielshiplett/actuator-test/tree/the-solution).

One possible way to enable ApplicationStartup data collection during a Spring Boot Test is to create a ContextCustomizer.  This allows you to get into the testing context early enough to record all of the data that you are looking for.  The ContextCustomizer should have a single static BufferingApplicationStartup that it registers as a singleton bean into the test context's bean factory.  It also needs to set the bean factory's ApplicationStartup because that will be passed to the SpringApplication just before it is run.

Here is the snippet of the customizer that holds the key:

```java
@Override
public void customizeContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();

    Object possibleSingleton = beanFactory.getSingleton(BEAN_NAME);

    // The only way it wouldn't be an instance of a BufferingApplicationStartup is if it is null or we haven't
    // run yet (and it is the DefaultApplicationStartup).  In either case, jam our BufferingApplicationStartup
    // in here.
    if(!(possibleSingleton instanceof BufferingApplicationStartup)) {
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(BEAN_NAME, APPLICATION_STARTUP);
        beanFactory.setApplicationStartup(APPLICATION_STARTUP);
    }
}
```

When you do this, make sure you implement a good equals and hashCode for your customizer or else you will break the test context caching and you will refresh your test context with every test class.  Since the only relevant part of the customizer is the static BufferingApplicationStartup, I chose to return its hashcode.

Finally, don't forget to add your ContextCustomizerFactory to the `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` or else the rest of the Spring Boot testing support won't see your customizer.

Once this is all setup, you can access the Startup Actuator endpoint just like you would any other actuator.